# C++ variables don't get deleted at the end of the scope

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, destructor, qmap

I have the following code snippet (which basically discoveres a given folder recursively) and I don't understand something about memory management in C++:

```
for(QFileInfo child : root.entryInfoList()) {
    if (child.isDir() &&
            child.absoluteFilePath() != rootInfo.absoluteFilePath() &&
            child.absoluteFilePath() != rootInfo.absolutePath())
    {
        discoverDirectory(child.absoluteFilePath());
    } else if (child.isFile()) {
        qDebug() << "Visiting file: " + child.absoluteFilePath();

        watchDog->addPath(child.absoluteFilePath());
        fileSysEntries.insert(child.absoluteFilePath(), child);
    }
}
```

As I remember, variables created without new are disposed of at the end of the scope, so whatever is in the *entryInfoList* it's going to be disposed of at the end of this function. So I thought this shouldn't work since I want to store the *child* items in the *fileSysEntries* QMap but they will be deleted after this call. However, I can access them later for some reason. I thought this is because the *child*'s copy constructor is called when inserting it into the *fileSysEntries* map but the insert function has the following signature:

```
iterator QMap::insert(const Key & key, const T & value)
```

where *value* is a call by name parameter, so the *child* items don't get copied I guess, which confuses me a little bit. Could someone show me what I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is passed to the `QMap` by reference (no copy here) and **afterwards** copied inside the map.

Comment: Passing by reference just means that the function is given the original object, not a copy.  It doesn't mean the function won't make its own copy internally.

Answer (score 2):

There are two copies being performed :

- `for(QFileInfo child : root.entryInfoList())` -  will create a copy of every object f rom the list.
- `fileSysEntries.insert(child.absoluteFilePath(), child);` - will also create a copy when inserting into a QMap.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the fact the `insert` (or `insertMulti`) function takes the value to be inserted by reference doesn't prevent it from making a copy afterwards.

And when you look at the Qt source code (`qmap.h`), it's actually what's happening:

```
template <class Key, class T>
Q_INLINE_TEMPLATE typename QMap<Key, T>::iterator 
QMap<Key, T>::insert(const Key &akey, const T &avalue)
{
    //Stuff
    last->value = avalue;//Here, a copy is made through copy assignement
    //Stuff
}
```